# What is happening in this recursion? I need to count down and back up using ONLY recursion/no loops

Tags: c++, function, recursion, counting

The problem that I'm solving is to take a number input by the user and then count down from that number by 5 until I reach a negative number and then counting back up by 5 until I get back to that number. I have to do this using only recursion with no looping at all. The code seams to work for the most part right until the value flips back around at 0.

```
void Func(int num, int base, bool flipped)
{
    cout << num << endl;

    if (flipped == false && num > 1)
    {
        Func(num - 5, base, flipped);
    }

    flipped = true;

    if (num < base)
    {
        Func(num + 5, base, true);
    }

    return;
}
```

The output that I'm getting from the above code with an input of 17 is:
17,
12,
7,
2,
-3,
2,
7,
12,
17,
7,
12,
17,
12,
17,
17.

it looks like there is an issue in the second recursion for some reason. What I've tried so far is making the bool static and adding return statements just about everywhere. Thank you for any help!

Comment: Please [make an appointment with your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: What kind of debugger are you using? If it is Visual C++, the call stack pane can help you.

Comment: Take note of where you return, and where you ... don't. What should happen when all the other recursive calls finish, and you get back to that point?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int recount(int num)
{
  std::cout<<num<<'\n';   \\Prints the current num
  if(num >= 0) \\checks that num is positive
  {
    \\recursively call the function counting down by 5
    std::cout<<recount(num-5)<<'\n';  
  }
  \\count up by 5 as we go back up 
  return num + 5;
}

int main()
{
  recount(17); \\ gives desired output
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```